# Keyboard Blocks The Screen When Typing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am making an app with multiple `UITextField` and `UITextView`
The `UITextView`is in the bottom of the screen and whenever typing starts, the keyboard blocks the `UITextView`

How will I able to move up the view of the form when the keyboard appears on the screen? then move it down again when the keyboard disappears?

Comment: Yep, you have to scroll the screen up while the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: And you really really couldn't find *any* answers to this *anywhere* on Stack Overflow or *anywhere*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is to try and avoid doing that.

However, if you put your stuff in a UIScrollView or a UITableView you can scroll to the input when it becomes first responder.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding
It works really well for me and is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you implement the UITextFieldDelegate in your class.  These delegate methods should do the trick for a text field named activeField:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [activeField setDelegate:self];    
    [self configureView];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return TRUE;
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```